# Getting a to do app to update or refresh, after clicking the save button

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, uibutton, reloaddata

Before starting just want to say that this is quite a long entry.

Have been having issues with table views and buttons and textfields. The main thing that me trying to do is create a to do list and have that at a separate page.

Have the user be able to enter a no task and click the save button and be able to swipe down the view for the textfield and saveButton. Going back to the main page which is the tableView, and having the entered value update or refresh to the tableview.

The problem is, as of right now me have to reset the application for the tableView to update. Have used the `reloadData()` and `ViewDidAppear()` methods. But the tableView does not want to update for some reason. Have entered value printing to the console, but after pressing the save button the console shows one behind each save button press. So no matter how many items added, the app is always one behind and the tableView does not refresh after pressing the save button.

Have been stuck on this problem for about a month now and am looking for help.

Here is a link to a YouTube video of the project running:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7cji9RUUpo&feature=youtu.be

Here is the code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    lazy var refreshData: UIRefreshControl = {
        let dataRefresh = UIRefreshControl();
        dataRefresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dataRequest), for: .valueChanged)
        self.tableView?.reloadData();
        return dataRefresh;   
    }()
    

    var listedCells: [String] = []
   
    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
       return listedCells.count
   
    }
    
    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      
       let cells = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "TDList")
        
        cells.textLabel?.text = listedCells[indexPath.row
        
        return cells  
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}
    
    @objc
    func dataRequest() {
        let endRefresh = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(400);
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: endRefresh) {
            self.refreshData.endRefreshing();
        }
        self.tableView?.reloadData();
        
        refreshData.endRefreshing();
       
        self.tableView?.reloadData();
        
    }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
          
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                tableView?.refreshControl = refreshData;
            } else {
                tableView?.addSubview(refreshData);
            }
              
            textField?.clearButtonMode = .always;
            textField?.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing;
            
            tableView?.delegate = self;
            tableView?.dataSource = self;
            
            let savedToDo = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ThingAdded")
            
            if let savedToList = savedToDo as? [String] {
                
                listedCells = savedToList;      
        }   
            self.tableView?.reloadData();
        
}
            
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit deleteSlider: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if deleteSlider == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            
            listedCells.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        
            self.tableView?.reloadData();
                   
            UserDefaults.standard.set(listedCells, forKey: "ThingAdded")
            
        }            
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any?) {
       
        let savedToDo = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ThingAdded")
        
        if let savedUpdated = savedToDo as? [String] {
            
            listedCells = savedUpdated;
            
            listedCells.append(textField.text!);
            
            print(listedCells);
            
        } else {
           
            listedCells = [textField.text!];
        }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(listedCells, forKey: "ThingAdded");
       
// right handed and left handed mode
     override   func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true);
    }  

   public     func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            
            return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 variables: `listedCells` and `listedCellss`.
On save, you are updating the listedCellss and UserDefaults, but listedCells gets updated only in `viewDidAppear`...

in saveButton function, at the end, just update your `listedCells` variable and then call:

```
self.tableView?.reloadData();
```

**EDIT** (After watching your video):

You have 2 View Controllers there: one where you press "Make Addition" (lets call it MainViewController) and another one with the "Save" button (lets call it AdditionViewController).
The table you want to update belongs to MainViewController, so when you press "Save", you actually need **MainViewController** to call reloadData.
You can achieve that using a callback:

In "AdditionViewController" define:

```
typealias ItemAddedCallback = () -> Void
var itemReadyCallback: ItemAddedCallback?

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any?) {
    ...
    itemReadyCallback?()
}
```

In "MainViewController" , override prepare method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    if let avc = segue.destination as? AdditionViewController {
        avc.itemReadyCallback = {
            self.tableView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**OR:**
You can define your segue presentation mode as "Full Screen" and then you can use `viewWillAppear` override to call reloadData on MainViewController. Without "Full Screen" viewWillAppear does not get invoked.

Comment: had updated the code and gotten rid of the listedCellss and put all to listedCells. The app updates in the console every press but the table view needs an app reset.let savedToDo = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ThingAdded")
        if let savedUpdated = savedToDo as? [String] {
            listedCells = savedUpdated
            listedCells.append(textField.text!)
            print(listedCells)
        } else {
            listedCells = [textField.text!]
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(listedCells, forKey: "ThingAdded")
        self.tableView?.reloadData() }

Comment: any help is still seriously appreciated!

Comment: did you remove the `var listedCellss: [String];` line as well? can you update your code in the question? Every time you call `reloadData` it will use your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt...` to reload, so as long as your instance's listedCells is update it should work

Comment: Uh yes the listedCells was deleted, also updated the code :/. Thanks for your time and apologies for such a late response